# User signup failing with using custom authentication filter in spring security 4.0.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I am trying to authentication user after user entity is created in the database in order to set the authenticated user in security context. But it is failing throwing **Bad Credentials** error.

Here is the code

```
 UserDetails userDetails = userAuthService.loadUserByUsername(form.getUsername());
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken loggedIn = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
            //loggedIn.setDetails(userDetails);
            authMgr.authenticate(loggedIn);
```

I am getting the userDetails properly. in the 1st statement.

I am using custom authentication like below

```
<authentication-manager alias="authMgr">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userAuthService">
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt"></password-encoder> 
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="userAuthService" class="com.csn.service.UserAuthService" >
</beans:bean>
```

And the UserAuthService class is like this.

```
public class UserAuthService implements UserDetailsService,Serializable{
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
    try{
        com.xxx.yyy.Authentication auth = new UserAuthDao().getUserByUsername(username);
        if(auth!=null){
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new com.xxx.ppp.GrantedAuthorityImpl(Constants.userRole));

            return new User(auth.getUsername(), auth.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
        }
        else{
            return  new User(username, "", true, true, true, true, null);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        log.error(className, "loadUserByUsername", e);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(loggedIn);
```

Comment: I am doing it, after the below statements.
authMgr.authenticate(loggedIn);
if(loggedIn.isAutenticated()){
     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(loggedIn);
}

Comment: I think problem is in this section: `return  new User(username, "", true, true, true, true, null);` null gives you BadCredentials. Change this part to `throw new UserNotFoundException();` and write in comments what is result of `userAuthService.loadByUsername(form.getUsername())`

Comment: got the solution. Should not have the authMgr.authenticate(loggedIn); statement as already loggedIn.authenticated filed is true.
I commented that authMgr.authenticate(loggedIn) and it worked. Thank you by the way.